# What's the simplest way to implement multisig ownership in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, multisignature

I have a list of owners in a smart contract and would like to require a minimum number of their approvals in order to execute some administrative functions. What's the simplest way to implement it? I am between using Gnosis Safe + Ownable but I would rather find a simpler and cheaper (in terms of gas costs) solution (preferable already audited). Do you know of any examples? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the problem given, a simple governance contract would be the best, where there should be a function to propose (only by owners), vote (only by owners), and execute/cancel (only by owners).
Execution of proposal itself should be very simple, checking if proposal is already executed, and execution of submitted target, value, method signature, and calldata.

For reference check:

- ***Hord protocol*** implementation of a simple multisig: HordCongress.sol contract https://github.com/hord/smart-contracts/blob/master/contracts/governance/HordCongress.sol
- ***Compound protocol*** implementation of governance contract: GovernorAlpha.sol contract https://github.com/compound-finance/compound-protocol/blob/master/contracts/Governance/GovernorAlpha.sol

Comment: First link returns 404?

Answer (score 1):

> Gnosis Safe + Ownable

This is the easiest and most robust way. The fees on Gnosis Safe 2.0 are not that massive, as you pay only once at the transaction execution.

Gas fees as what they are and they are outside of your control.

Comment: Thanks! Could you link a simple example of this implementation?

Comment: https://github.com/dawn-Protocol/dawn-erc20-erc777

Comment: I see it uses Ownable and that the owner can be a multisig, but coudln't find where it is actually deploying the multisig or any examples of that. Do you know if I can use GnosisSafe without their UI and in Ropsten? And if there is any documentation of a simple example of how to use it, sign messages, etc? Thanks!

Comment: You can deploy a new contract from Gnosis Safe UI itself. If not then you deploy the contract by hand or in a test suite as well. They might not support Ropsten, but they supported some test networks in the past.

Comment: Using the Gnosis Safe is so simple that it does not need documentation.